# create spring boot 2.7 'mvn spring-boot:build-image' with podman on macOS failed

Tags: spring-boot, podman

I try to create an image with `mvn spring-boot:build-image` using podman but got

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.0:build-image (default-cli) @ sample-spring-service ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/sample-spring-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:94e65320ba1682bc68cbbf1d4f63693bb62cc06c7077bfa3e3bccac7fdc10628'
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:base-cnb' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:3e889016680c0e2ef1e8b1bfdad2d6d34966c860a53ccfcfb3e269d48ed65fed'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.14.1
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-744ddec35876.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: initializing analyzer: getting previous image: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

podman info:

```
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.26.1
  cgroupControllers:
...
version:
  APIVersion: 4.1.0
  Built: 1651853754
  BuiltTime: Fri May  6 18:15:54 2022
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.18
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 4.1.0
```

I already tried a lot. Set permissions on socket, run podman with root. The same with docker is working well.

`podman create alpine ls` works fine.

In my pom.xml I tried:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <docker>
                    <!--  <host>unix:///Users/mike/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/podman-machine-default/podman.sock</host>
                        <host>unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock</host>
                    -->
                        <bindHostToBuilder>true</bindHostToBuilder>
                    </docker>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Any idea?

Update:

If I enable this line in pom.xml:

unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock

I get:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.0:build-image (default-cli) @ sample-spring-service ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/sample-spring-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[INFO] I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->docker://localhost:2376: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory
[INFO] Retrying request to {}->docker://localhost:2376
[INFO] I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->docker://localhost:2376: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory
[INFO] Retrying request to {}->docker://localhost:2376
[INFO] I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->docker://localhost:2376: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory
[INFO] Retrying request to {}->docker://localhost:2376
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' 100%
```

Comment: The Maven output indicates that Spring Boot is talking to podman as expected (pulling images etc). Boot then invokes processes inside the CNB builder image, and the processes in the container also need to talk to podman. It's the `creator` process inside the CNB builder container that's failing. The `<bindHostToBuilder>true</bindHostToBuilder>` that you're setting should bind `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` to the configured `<docker><host>` in the builder container, but I'm not sure what's going on with the permissions.

Comment: Can you try doing the same with the `pack` CLI as described in the CNB docs? After building a jar with Boot, you'd do something like `pack build sample-spring-service -p target/sample-spring-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -B paketobuildpacks/builder:base`. https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/building-on-podman/

Comment: ```pack build sample-spring-service -p target/sample-spring-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -B paketobuildpacks/builder:base``` - works.

Comment: I just tested this again on Ubuntu 22.04 with podman 3.4.4 and 4.1.1, and was successful with both versions using the Maven plugin configuration shown in the Boot docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.docker.podman). With podman 4.1 I had to run `podman system service --time=0` to get the podman API server listening on the `podman.sock` socket. If you're still getting errors after making sure the API service is started, can you share more info about your OS and other local env details?

Comment: If you were running this on a Linux distro with SELinux enabled, you were probably running into this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32000

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into a similar issue with spring boot build-image, for example when using remote docker hosts

From what I understand:

- the pull is done using your docker parameters in pom.xml or environment variables like DOCKER_HOST
- Once the pull has been completed, creator will start a new container and run the next commands in this newly container
- The connection to docker in the new container might not work, as the DOCKER_HOST might need to be different for access to docker within a new container. Within the "creator" container, /var/run/docker.sock is automatically mounted from the host system.
- If you enable bindHostToBuilder, it'll pass the DOCKER_HOST (or the parameter in pom.xml) to the new container, but that might not be the correct docker hostname that is accessible from within the new container.

For me the solution was to not use bindHostToBuilder, but ensure that /var/run/docker.sock exists on the host system so that it can be mapped within the "creator" container, even though the pull happens with a different DOCKER_HOST (a remote docker)